# Link MKL statically in MPI program

Tags: linker, fortran, openmp, intel-mkl

I have a Fortran MPI program that uses openMP and MKL. On my personal computer I would compile with the Intel compiler by calling something like `mpiifort Program.F90 -i8 -qmkl -fopenmp -o run`, and then run the program as `mpirun ./run`.

I would like to run this program on a cluster, where I have access to Intel MPI but no other libraries. Hence I need to link MKL statically. From the Intel MKL Link Line Advisor I obtain the following,

`-Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl`

This line is set up such that MKL will parallelize with openMP, which I want for my code. However if I try to run this code on the cluster, I get the error: `error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Seemingly my attempt to link parallelized MKL has not been fully static, since it still tries to link dynamically. Is there any way in which I can circumvent this problem, i.e. link the openMP threaded version of MKL in a fully static way?

Thanks!

Comment: Your link line has `-liomp5`. Spell that one out: use the explicit `.a` version.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have fixed it

Comment: Be very careful, though. Having more than one OpenMP runtime linked into the same code can lead to poor performance due to each using its own thread pool... ( What you're doing is likely OK as you'll still only have one OpenMNP runtime, whereas statically linking OpenMP into each static library when it is built is potentially not!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that here is an issue while loading the shared libraries. Please use libiomp5.a as pointed out by Victor Eijkhout. It is present under  /opt/intel/lib/intel64. This helps to link the openMP threaded version of MKL in a complete statical way as per your requirement.